# Which database to use for educational android application??

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am developing one android application for which I need to use database but I am confused between MySQL and SQLite. My application consists of one questionnaire having 4-5 test papers and generates automatic report on the basis of answers given by user. But as a newbie in the area of application development, I couldn't decide which database is good for my application.

Comment: use sQlite because it's already integrated into android already, the only reason you should use mysql is when you want to connect your website to an external web service i.e you are fetching the question via an existing web application

Comment: I don't have website. But will SQLite be able to handle large amount of data??

Comment: yes for you purpose it should handle it well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this database supposed to be on the phone, or is it supposed to be on a server where the results can be saved for grading/other use?  If its on the device only, then SQLite is your only option.  If its meant for use on a server where results are being sent back to, then SQLite is probably not the right choice-  MySql, Posgresql, or other similar product would make more sense.

Comment: Yes. This database is supposed to be on the phone as I don't have any website for the same. but will SQLite be able to handle large amount of data?? eg. Users of this application will be primary school teachers who can enter details for all students of their class.